# Android onClick(View) with switch incorrect case

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I have a single `OnClickListener` instance to direct clicks to multiple other handler methods, generally:

```
void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.viewA:
        handleButtonA();
        break;
    case R.id.viewB:
        handleButtonB();
        break;
    default:
        handleDefaultCondition();
        break;
    }
}
```

When I click view A, `handleButtonA()` is called.  When I click view B, nothing happens.  When I click any other view it calls `handleDefaultCondition()`.  I had the same behavior with a series of `if/else if` statements, so I don't *think* the problem is related to my use of `switch`.

Here is the complete code:

```
public class MyClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int viewId = view.getId();
            switch (viewId) {
            case R.id.time_frag_mark_button:
                handleMarkButton();  //just calls dummy method with a Log statement inside for testing
                break;
            case R.id.finalize_entry_button:
                handleFinalizeButton();  //just calls dummy method with a Log statement inside for testing
                break;
            default:
                openTimePickerDialog(view.getId());  //just calls dummy method with a Log statement inside for testing
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

And an excerpt from my R file:

```
public static final class id {
    public static final int action_settings=0x7f08000e;
    public static final int finalize_entry_button=0x7f08000d;
    public static final int separator=0x7f080002;
    public static final int time_frag_current_time=0x7f080003;
    public static final int time_frag_date_string=0x7f080001;
    public static final int time_frag_in_label=0x7f08000b;
    public static final int time_frag_in_picker=0x7f08000c;
    public static final int time_frag_mark_button=0x7f080004;
}
```

As requested, the code to initialize the listeners:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myClickListener = new MyClickListener();
    myTimeFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK);
    myTimeTicker = new MyTimeTicker();
    getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(myTimeTicker, myTimeFilter);
    systemTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time_frag_current_time);
    systemTime.setText(sdf.format(new Date()));
    systemDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time_frag_date_string);
    outTimeView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time_frag_out_picker);
    outTimeView.setOnClickListener(myClickListener);
    offTimeView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time_frag_off_picker);
    offTimeView.setOnClickListener(myClickListener);
    onTimeView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time_frag_on_picker);
    onTimeView.setOnClickListener(myClickListener);
    inTimeView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time_frag_in_picker);
    inTimeView.setOnClickListener(myClickListener);
    markButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.time_frag_mark_button);
    markButton.setOnClickListener(myClickListener);
    //should error check this, only open a new one if one is not in progress
    //need to start saving the Entry to disk during onPause() and move this check to onStart() or something
    currentEntry = new LogEntry();
}
```

Comment: Do you set a listener for view with id = R.id.viewB? I know it is pretty stupid but very often happens.

Comment: *"When I click view B, nothing happens.*" - that suggests `onClick()` doesn't even get called, because if it would, then at least the `default` of the `switch` would be executed. From the sounds of it, you may be missing an `OnClickListener` on `B`, as pointed out above.

Comment: Yep you guys are right, I added the finalize button later, and forgot to even declare/initialize it.  I just added it to the xml and the onClick method.  Oops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried looking to see what ID is output when you press the `R.id.finalize_entry_button` to see if it is what you expect?

Also, can you post the code that hooks up the OnClick handler to your controls?